# How to learn about audio recording and production

Tags: audio-recording

I have little knowledge in audio recording and production. I wonder how I shall learn about it?

1. As a beginner, some introductory
   material that give general ideas and
   big picture will be great.

   As I continue to learn, some 
   comprehensive references will
   probably be needed to consult
   from time to time.

   The materials and references can be
   of any form, books, webpages, ...
2. Some good software on computer for
   audio recording and production,
   which can improve my understanding
   by playing around? Some people
   recommend Audacity. Is it a good
   choice?

Currently I just hope to make and manipulate some audio files on my personal computer, but I would also like to open my eyes to know about how professionals work.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: i think you might want to change the title of your question now that the name changed to "Audio-Video Production"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For introductory material, you won't go far wrong with getting a few books by Paul White (editor of [Sound on Sound magazine](http://www.soundonsound.com/)). He's done a whole series of really [helpful short books](http://www.amazon.co.uk/paul-white-Books/s?ie=UTF8&keywords=paul%2bwhite&rh=n:266239,k%3apaul%2bwhite&page=1#/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=stripbooks&field-keywords=paul%2bwhite%20basic&rh=n:266239,k%3apaul%2bwhite%20basic), including:

- Basic Digital Recording
- Basic Microphones
- Basic Mixing Techniques
- Basic Home Studio Design
- Basic Effects and Processors
- Basic Mastering
- Basic VST Instruments
- Basic VST Effects
- Basic Multitracking
- Basic Mixers
- Basic Sampling
- Basic Live Sound
- Basic MIDI

As for your second question, Audacity is a decent free recording application, good for recording and editing single audio files, or producing podcasts. If music recording is your thing, and you want to record MIDI, or use lots of VST effects, then a digital audio workstation (DAW) would probably be more appropriate. I've used and can recommend [REAPER](http://www.reaper.fm/) and [SONAR](http://www.cakewalk.com/products/sonar/), but there are lots of others to choose from.